# Facebook Stack Overflow logo missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, facebook.stackoverflow

When navigating to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com there doesn't seem to be a logo at the top.

[image: Logo missing]

[The file for it isn't there](http://cdn2.sstatic.net/stackoverflowimg/so-fb-logo.png?v=2)

Comment: -1 No freehand circles. Where is your heart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We made some backend changes this morning and this seems to have fallen out of the loop (it is a very special case site).

Sorted now.