# More 404s with missing slashes

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, 404-not-found, cdn

See [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182486/facebook-stack-overflow-logo-missing).

The problem was that Stack Overflow was trying to access

```
http://cdn2.sstatic.net/stackoverflowimg/so-fb-logo.png?v=2
```

When it should have done this:

```
http://cdn2.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/so-fb-logo.png?v=2
```

---

I have been experiencing similar problems all over Stack Exchange. For example, here's one from math.SE (click image to enlarge):

[image]

From gamedev.SE:

[image]

It says:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

And the URL that returned a 404 was

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/imgnewsletter-ad.png
```

Not surprisingly, [adding a slash worked](http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/img/newsletter-ad.png):

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/img/newsletter-ad.png
```

I've been seeing these types of 404s on many other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Blame Oded :P..

Comment: @Seth hey no odedism please! :D

Comment: [He dunnit...](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/86/embedded/result/)

Comment: @Seth - so now we blame the person who fixes em'?

Comment: @Oded More or less.  It *was* a joke :-P

Comment: [This is simply a meta rep scam! 1) Introduce bool error hiding an often clicked component 2) Wait for meta to blow up 3) Post answer, saving the day 4) Go to 1)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180721/missing-meta-chat-faq-from-top-navigation-reward-offered/180724#comment548667_180724)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like we missed some spots where we were building the image paths.

Should be OK now.

Comment: unaccept; no longer fixed :( see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184367/180276)

Comment: @Doorknob - Yeah. We missed a spot.