# Icons not appearing in Inbox email notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, email-notification

Overnight I received two "1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox" emails, both of which have a blank site icon.

Math: [Mathematics Stack Exchange http://cdn.sstatic.net/mathimg/icon-48.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/mathimg/icon-48.png)

Computational Science: [Computational Science Stack Exchange http://cdn.sstatic.net/scicompimg/icon-48.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/scicompimg/icon-48.png)

Comment: Gah, it's [this again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182650/more-404s-with-missing-slashes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

We missed the email images when fixing the others.

Fix will be in the next build.

Comment: The bug is back... In the latest email I got, it links to http://stackoverflow.com//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/icon-48.png

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the URLs:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/mathimg/icon-48.png
http://cdn.sstatic.net/scicompimg/icon-48.png
```

Now, I remember (because I asked [this question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182650/more-404s-with-missing-slashes)) that sometimes URLs will break because there is a missing slash before `img` in the URL.

Adding the slashes like this

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/img/icon-48.png
http://cdn.sstatic.net/scicomp/img/icon-48.png
```

used to fix it; nowadays, HTTPS is preferred and the site-specific icons have been moved into the Sites directory:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/math/img/icon-48.png
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/scicomp/img/icon-48.png
```

[image]
[image]

[The question earlier referenced in my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182650/more-404s-with-missing-slashes) is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but this bug has returned!