# Missing image in ad for newsletter subscription

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, newsletter, 404-not-found

When I navigate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794716/android-url-content-to-string) (not logged in), I see an ad about subscribing to newsletters. However, its image is missing.

[image: Broken image in ad for newsletter subscription]

Its image path is:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflowimg/apple-touch-icon.png
```

which is broken (HTTP 404). I think it should be:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png
```

i.e., with a '/' between `stackoverflow` and `img`.

---

Aw man! This bug is so hard to reproduce! I refreshed like a hundred times and finally I see again on [this question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/508049/what-kind-of-network-attack-turns-a-switch-into-a-hub):

The wrong URL:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/serverfaultimg/apple-touch-icon.png
```

The right URL:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/serverfault/img/apple-touch-icon.png
```

What a way to make me see all your ads!

---

Oh, just found [a similar question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182486/204869), but it's [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) so I guess this one is different?